# Recreating in Mathematica a matrix created in Python

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays, python, index

I need to recreate in Mathematica this matrix that I created in Python:

```python
K = zeros((n, n), float)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1):
        i_shifted = i + 2
        j_shifted = j + 1

        K[i][j] = ((3.0*70.0*70.0*0.3)/(2.0*300000.0*300000.0))*((j_shifted*(i_shifted-j_shifted))/i_shifted)*(1.0 + (70.0/300000.0)*j_shifted)
```

What I have done so far is the following piece of code:

```
Kmatrix = 
  Table[((3.0*70.0*70.0*0.3)/(2.0*300000.0*300000.0))*((j + 1)*(i + 
        2 - (j + 1)))*(1.0 + (70.0/300000.0)*(j + 1)), {i, 0, 
    n - 1}, {j, 0, i}];
```

But it's wrong, because what I get if I do

```
Kmatrix // MatrixForm
```

is not even a matrix.
I know that the error should be in

```
{j, 0, i}
```

but how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this correctly generate your K for n==3?  n = 3;
K = Table[0., {n}, {n}];
For[i = 0, i < n, i++,
  For[j = 0, j < i + 1, j++,
   ishifted = i + 2; jshifted = j + 1;
   K[[i + 1, j + 1]] = 3.0*70.0*70.0*0.3/(2.0*300000.0*300000.0)*
     jshifted*(ishifted - jshifted)/ishifted*(1.0 + 70.0/300000.0*jshifted)
   ]
  ];
K

Comment: There's a reason many of your questions have been closed. Make the effort to *understand* the answers offered, implementing simpler cases if needed until you get a handle on the basic functionality of the product. *Read* the documentation. *Read* the FAQ/Tutorials on this very site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `Table`, use

```
If[j <= i, (* your expression *), 0]
```

and change the iterators to go `{i, 0, n-1}, {j, 0, n-1}`.

Also:

I think your code would become more readable if you used `{i, 1, n}` and instead of `i+1` everywhere just write `i`.  You're not using `i` and `j` as indices into an array with `Table` and even if you were: Mathematica uses 1-based indexing.